# can't get soap working under php 5.3

Tags: soap, php-5.3

I'm trying to use soap under php 5.3... I keep having the following issue when I try the first call. Both server & client are created without errors. But when I try the first call, I get the following error:

```
> SoapFault Object (
>     [message:protected] => Authorization Required
>     [string:private] => 
>     [code:protected] => 0
>     [file:protected] => /my/site/dir/tests/client.php
>     [line:protected] => 21
>     [trace:private] => Array
```

Don't understand what is not working and why it needs access right on my client code ????

Comment: found my problem.... .htaccess was blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options :
+ either you get the soap server to acessible
+ or you use the login/password options in creating soapserver & soapclient